# Include quotes within a select concat statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

How can I pass a string value within a concat statement?

for example, I want the following string:
My name is 'XYZ'

The sql script for this will be:

```
select concat 'My name is' + 'XYZ'
```

In the output of the above script, the string XYZ will not be in quotes.
Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: This question seems like it was attempting to do a `CONTACT()` function, i.e. Concat statement. So, I'm not so sure this question is actually a duplicate, but I think some of those answers are applicable.

Answer (score -3):

Double up single quotes to include them in a string:

```
select 'My name is' + '''XYZ'''
```

Comment: not sure what merited these down votes.. `''` is escaping, thus `'''XYZ'''` does result in `'XYZ'` varchar\string.  which is what you would use with `Select CONCAT('My name is ', '''XYZ''')` ... note that this answer's approach, which is correct, is not on the source question.  perhaps it's worth adding there.

Comment: @BrettCaswell - answering questions which are clearly duplicates is not encouraged as it defeats the purpose of the site.